# Controlling `\subsection` output at `.toc` file

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, tocloft

Consider the following simple code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage [english] {babel}
\begin{document} 
    \tableofcontents
    \section{One}
    \subsection{Two}
    \subsection{Three}
\end{document}
```

It will produce the `.toc` file with the following inside

```
\select@language {english}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}One}{1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Two}{1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2}Three}{1}
```

Then if I will format my table of contents with `tocloft` package I will always have a deal with numbers of sections formatted as `<section>.<subsection>`. My question is if it is possible to control output of `\subsection` command into `.toc` file to obtain in `.toc` file numbers of subsections formatted as `<subsection>`:

```
\select@language {english}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}One}{1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Two}{1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2}Three}{1}
```

(P.S. I use `titlesec` and `titleloft` packages and then if there are no proper easy solution I would like to have a solution that doesn't affect work of these packages).

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). How do you want to have the numbering inside the main document?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `subsection` counter not to be subordinated to the `section` counter?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina no, I want it to be subordinated but it seems that `\subsection` prints `\thesection.\thesubsection` and I only want it to print `\thesubsection` instead

Comment: @Nimza ah, I see. egreg has already provided an answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes, but the answer of egreg doesn't change `.toc` file, so if you know how to control output of `\subsection` into a `.toc` file I will be very thankful if you tell about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the package `tocloft` and the `\cftsubsecpresnum` macro to eat up the section  number and the period:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\def\cftsubsecpresnum#1.{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{one}
\subsection{two}
\subsection{three}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If there are also chapters and the subsection number is like x.y.z, you should eat up two parts:

```
\def\cftsubsecpresnum#1.#2.{}
```

The package `tocloft` puts `\cftsubsecpresnum` in front of the section number when typesetting the TOC. So TeX "sees", for instance

```
\cftsubsecpresnum 1.2
```

and expands `\cftsubsecpresnum`; my redefinition of the macro tells TeX that it has an argument and this argument is everything that follows the macro up to the first period (you can't use `\renewcommand` in this case). Since the replacement text is empty, the 1 and the period will simply disappear from the input stream together with `\cftsubsecpresnum` and only the 2 will remain.

If you say `\def\cftsubsecpresnum#1.{\S}` in place of `1.` an `\S` will appear.

Arguments specified in this way are called *delimited*; ordinary arguments (those looked for when a macro is defined with `\newcommand`) are just one token or an entire group in braces. This macro will work also for "subsection 10.11", because all up to the period is defined to be the argument.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It works nice (I use `\def\cftsubsecpresnum#1.{\S}`). If it isn't difficult to you, tell me please or give me a reference, how to use  such things as #1 and #2 here (I know only about parameters with such notation).